# how to display multiple values, separated by commas, at single columns?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am using mysql to perform queries. have the following 7 tables.

- appointment        //non-atomic, eg. values ->      1,7,3
- gender             //atomic value
- module             //non-atomic, eg. values ->      12,33
- program
- rank
- staff
- student

I have tried 'concat', 'find_in_set' & 'in' functions but cannot get it to work. How may I display multiple values @ relations 'appointment' & 'module'?

The following statement is the closest i can get. Please let me know if additional details are required, thank you.

```
SELECT sta.staName
      , r.rank
      , sta.appointmentID
      , a.appointment
      , m.moduleCode 
  FROM staff AS sta 
 JOIN rank AS r 
    ON (sta.rankID = r.rankID) 
 JOIN appointment AS a 
ON (sta.appointmentID = a.appointmentID) 
 JOIN module AS m 
    ON (sta.teachModuleID = m.moduleID) 
  WHERE sta.genderID = 1;
```

Comment: Have you thought of changing the DB design?

Comment: thank you. yes, but given my current situation i cant. any workaround please? i understand that the design is not normalized.

Comment: i believe all i need is a tweak to the current sql statement & it shld be able to work, but cannot get it right yet?

Comment: Of course you can redesign this. And you should.

Comment: thank you both, ive tried juergen's suggestn it gave multiple results. in any way, ive changed the title.

Comment: sorry, as in the multiple values are within a column in each row, & i wish to display those multiple values.

Comment: You now have two problems. The first is obviously a lack of normalisation, but this is 'normally' pretty easy to fix. The second involves a confusion between data retrieval and data display. Issues of data display are best handled in a presentation layer/application-level code, if that's available.

Comment: @ strawberry: yes i understand that it is not normalized & it violates even 1NF. but still, given the current design, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sta.staName, r.rank, sta.appointmentID, 
       group_concat(distinct a.appointment) as appointments,
       group_concat(distinct m.moduleCode) as moduleCodes
FROM staff AS sta 
INNER JOIN rank AS r ON sta.rankID = r.rankID
INNER JOIN appointment AS a ON find_in_set(sta.appointmentID, a.appointmentID) > 0
INNER JOIN module AS m ON find_in_set(sta.teachModuleID, m.moduleID) > 0
WHERE sta.genderID = 1
GROUP BY sta.staName, r.rank, sta.appointmentID
```

Comment: This will return all the modules each time. That doesn't appear to fit with the requirement as set out in the title (although I suspect the OP meant 'row' instead of 'column')

Comment: thank you juergen. so given the situation & i cant redesign the tables as of yet, how can i do what i need as per the title?

Comment: Any more suggestions sir?

Comment: Please be more specific. How is my query different from the result you expect?

Comment: dear sir, for eg, a particular staff may hold several appointments & teach several modules. so i wish to display the appointments & modules each staff holds or teaches respectively. your query returns only the 1st appointment & 1st module @ ea row. so sorry, please guide me.

Comment: in other words, a staff @ a particular row may hold only 1 appointment as well

Comment: dear sir, thank you! your query worked when i switched the parameters within find_in_set! solved.